# disable overwriting calc() in sass

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

In SASS my Calculation looks like `calc(50% - 375px);` But when it compiles the CSS output looks like that: `calc(-325%)`, which is obviously not what I had in mind.

How can I force SASS to not do the maths `(50% - 375px)`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you show the complete code block where the issue occurs? You shouldn't get the outcome you're getting so something else isn't right.

Comment: You'll need string interpolation there `height: calc(50% - #{375})`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I already tried string interpolation but it didn't worked. I also tried using variables instead, but nevertheless the compiled outcome was as mentioned.

Comment: @sidonaldson SASS: `.test{ background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0px, white calc(50% - 375px), white calc(50% - 375px), white calc(50% + 375px), white calc(50% + 375px), red 100%);}` -> CSS: `.test{ background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0px, white calc(-325%), ...);}`

Answer (score 3):

Use the SASS interpolation like this `#{'calc(50% - 375px)'};`

Comment: This worked for me in a slightly different use-case: `font-size: #{'min(max(2.4rem, 7vw), 4.5rem)'}` to stop SASS from applying it's own min() and max() functions. Though, according to the docs it should not https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/special-functions#min-and-max. Probably depends on the compiler?

Comment: @nabrown maybe compiler or compiler version

Answer (score 0):

Using the [unquote](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/string#unquote) function worked for me:

```
.selector { 
    height: unquote("calc(50% - 375px)"); 
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me, still outputs the final calculated result

Answer (score 0):

We still ran into compile issue using escaped strings, but using capitalized `Min` worked for us.

Ref: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2849#issuecomment-922070076

Answer (score -1):

Use escaped string: ~"(50% - 375px)";

Comment: Error: Invalid CSS after "    width:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was '~"(100% - 45px) / 5' in two separate compilers. Any ideas?