# how can I make a grid using flexbox with a fixed spacing between child divs?

Tags: css

the idea is not to use any framework.

Basically I am using a .`row` class that will contain my grid and it will be `flexbox`. Each child will have a class that will say how much `width` it will occupy (something like the bootstrap grid), so for example:

```
.col1: {width: 25%};  
.col2: {width: 50%};  
.col3: {width: 75%}; 
.col4: {width: 100%};
```

if I put 4 divs with the class .`col1` they should be in the same line because they would occupy `25%` of the container (`.row`), but if I put one more `div` it would go down to another line because it exceeded `100%` of the container.

```
|| col1 | col1 | col1 | col1 || //4 divs each div with 25% in the same .row.


|| col1 | col1 | col1 | col1 || //5 divs each div with 25% in the same .row.
|| col1 |                     | 


||        col3        | col1 || //2 divs 1 of 75% other of 25% .row.
```

The problem is that my grid should always contain a space of **20px between each element**, something like the following image:

[image]

I don't know how to put a space between each div and still comply with the above rules, if I have 4 `divs` with class `.col1` they must be in the same line (including the space).
If I have a div with `.col3` and another with `.col1` it should be:

[image]

how can I do it?

I tried this: (`gap` between the divs exceeds the percentages of the `div's width`,this is the reason why the `divs` in this example are not in the same line even though there are 4 `divs` that should occupy 100% of the `.row` since each one would have 25% of the `width`.
)

```css
html,body{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 box-sizing: border-box
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100%;
  gap: 20px;
  
}

.row div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  background:yellow;
  font-size:24px;
  text-align:center;
  height:100px;
 }
 
.col1{
 width:25%;
}
.col2{
 width:50%;
}
.col3{
 width:75%;
}
.col4{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
</div>
```

how can fix it? or is there any better way to achieve this?

**NOTE:** I need no spaces at the beginning of the first `div` of the `.row`, nor at the end of the last `div` of the `.row`

Comment: You might be looking for `grid-gap: xpx`

Comment: @RizaKhan I've tried gap, but it hasn't worked for me, or I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some CSS variables to make the calculation you want:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
}

.row {
  --g:20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  gap: var(--g);
}

.col1 {width:calc((100% - 3*var(--g))*1/4 + 0*var(--g))}
.col2 {width:calc((100% - 3*var(--g))*2/4 + 1*var(--g))}
.col3 {width:calc((100% - 3*var(--g))*3/4 + 2*var(--g))}
.col4 {width:calc((100% - 3*var(--g))*4/4 + 3*var(--g))}


.row div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col2">col2</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col3">col3</div>
  <div class="col1">col1</div>
  <div class="col2">col2</div>
  <div class="col2">col2</div>
  <div class="col4">col4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! can you explain to me your mathematical logic, please? I don't understand :( . Thanks, Genious

Comment: @yavgz you have 4 columns so 3 gaps. you first remove all the gaps `100% - 3*gap` then you multiply that value using `i/4` where  `i` is the number of column you need to consider [from 1 to 4]. finally we add gaps to the width because an element can cross the gapq. An element having 4 columns will contain 3 gaps, the one with 3 column 2 gaps, 2 columns 1 gaps, 1 columns 0 gaps.

Comment: Thanks crack, I have a comment, if you use  `0*var(--g)` using `sass` you will have an error

Comment: @yavgz https://stackoverflow.com/a/52422927/8620333

Answer (score 1):

You might use `calc()`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.row div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col1 {
  min-width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.col2 {
  min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.col3 {
  min-width: calc(75% - 20px);
}

.col4 {
  min-width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">col1</div>
    <div class="col1">col1</div>
    <div class="col1">col1</div>
    <div class="col1">col1</div>

    <div class="col1">col1</div>
    <div class="col2">col2</div>
    <div class="col1">col1</div>

    <div class="col1">col1</div>
    <div class="col3">col3</div>

    <div class="col4">col4</div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks! why do you use `min-width` instead of `width`?

Comment: why add `20px` in `.row` width? and why `margin-left:-10px`;

Comment: there is a space at the end of the last div :(

Comment: @yavgz, yes, there are 10px margins at the left and right sides, but it's easy to hide them.

Comment: how can I remove first and last spaces?

Comment: @yavgz, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure, but I don't like the solution of using overflow: hidden, will there be another way?

Comment: @yavgz, it's up to you which solution to use. "I don't like" looks like a weak reason to me. Try to use grid layout =))

Comment: thanks man, I mean that simply space is going to exist, it is just hiding, I don't have the knowledge, but I think there would be a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add one more child tag to contain the content of a **col**.

```css
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 100%;
            /* gap: 20px; */
        }

        .row div {
            /* border: 1px solid blue; */
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 100px;
        }

        .col1 {
            width: 25%;
        }

        .col2 {
            width: 50%;
        }

        .col3 {
            width: 75%;
        }

        .col4 {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .col1>* {
            background: yellow;
            margin: 0 20px;
        }

        .col3>* {
            background: yellow;
            margin: 0 20px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1">
            <div>col1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
            <div>col1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
            <div>col1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
            <div>col1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <div>col3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col1">
            <div>col1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: almost perfect, but see that there is a space at the beginning and at the end, the space should only exist between the divs.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the pixels that you are using to separate each div are part of the % of the all that div, as you say, exceeds the percentages of the div's width.
I mean, if that space between cols is mandatory, you need to do 25% - 20px, and so on for each col

Comment: thanks but, this not works.. divs on the other line :(